# Serial port communication with Apache Web Server

Tags: apache, serial-port

I'm trying to deploy a web application based on ASP.NET to Apache/mod-mono
The application is for my personnal use only as it is not safe at all : I have to access to a serial port of the web server ! 
When I run my application on windows (with the server in VS2010), everything is going great, I can have access to the serial port and communicate through it, but things are going bad when I try it on a Apache server. My web application has a proper behavior, but I get an Internal Server Error when I try to access to the serial port.

I think the problem comes from a lack of permission for the server to access to the serial port, but how can I overcome this issue ?

Comment: did u find a solution for this? I am trying to do the same thing using apache2 and django